# How to mathematically and/or programmatically find if an integer can't be written as a sum of defined integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can you mathematically and/or programmatically find if an integer can't be expressed as a sum of defined integers?

For example, defined integers are 3, 7, 37 and 73.
Now let's say that you need to find if certain number under 200 can't be written as a sum of defined integers. Like, check if what is the highest number that can't be written using defined integers.
How could this be done?

I found a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473501/find-if-an-integer-can-be-written-as-a-sum-of-n-positive-integers-with-only-k-un) but there is no answer there and it's not exactly what I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lookup the subset sum problem. A well known NP-complete problem.

Comment: By "defined" integers I guess you mean a given set of integers?? Then yeah it's subset sum. It's NP-hard.

Comment: If you are looking for solutions that may work well for you depending on what kinds of integers you are dealing with, look up subset sum problem as indicated and specifically look for "dynamic programming" solution.

Comment: You may be interested in watching [NumberPhile's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNTSugyS038) about "McNugget numbers" which is the same problem but with the integers $6,9,20$.  They mention at the end of the video that some other names of the generalized problem is the "Frobenius problem" or "Coin problem."  Searching those terms might yield more results.

Comment: If the "defined integers" can be used more than once then this problem is often called a *restricted partition* problem.

Comment: Going by your own answer it sounds like you were asking about the [Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_coin_problem).

Answer (score 3):

You can program a solution to that problem, it is called the subset sum problem. Sadly the problem is NP-complete which means that there is no known polynomial time algorithm to solve it.

You have 2 options, you can use the "bruteforce" decision tree solution which is $\mathcal{O} (2^N)$ where N is the number of "defined" numbers.

You can use the dynamic programming solution which has a runtime of $\mathcal{O}(sN)$ where $s$ is your target sum and $N$ is the number of "defined" numbers (even though this looks polynomial, it is actually exponential in the number of bits needed to describe it).

With your given example both of the solutions would be sufficient. But once you start making your list of "defined" numbers bigger, the dynamic programming solution should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for answering!
Found my solution! I used subset sum problem C# algorithm I found and modified my list.

If I have 3, 7, 37 and 73 in my list, the algorithm will not return true if int passed in is 6, because it will not try 3 + 3, only 3 + 7 etc. That means it can't solve bigger numbers than the sum of a list (120). So I used a for loop and made my list contain like ten threes, ten sevens and so on.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/AMWNSntB) the code I used.
Console prints out "Biggest number that doesn't contain 3, 7, 37 nor 73 is 11".

Math & programming rules!

Comment: This, then, is the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem), and you have just calculated the [Frobenius number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#Frobenius_numbers_for_small_n) of $\{3,7,37,73\}$.